# Gaussian mean width of normal random cones

Tags: pr.probability, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, cones

Suppose $1 \leq n < m < \infty$ are integers. For $g \sim \mathcal N(0, I_n)$ define the gaussian mean width of a non-empty set $T \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ by 
$$
w(T) := \mathbb E \sup_{x \in T} \langle x, g \rangle.
$$
Given $a_1, \ldots, a_m \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal N(0, I_n)$, define $T_m' := \mathrm{cvx}\{a_j : j \in [m]\}$ and let $T_m := \mathrm{cone}(T_m')$. Here, $\mathrm{cvx}(\cdot)$ denotes the convex hull of its argument and $\mathrm{cone}(K) := \bigcup_{\lambda \geq 0} \lambda K$ denotes the cone of a set $K$.

My goal is to find a bound on $w(T_m \cap \mathbb S^{n-1})$ which is not agnostic of the direction information (*i.e.,* has some dependence on $\langle a_j, a_k \rangle, j, k \in [m]$). For example, it would be sufficient for the bound to depend on the coherence $\mu := \max_{1 \leq j \neq k\leq m} |\langle a_j, a_k\rangle|$. In this case, a desirable statement might look something like:

> With high probability on the realization of $\{a_j : j \in [m]\}$, the coherence of the vectors is at most $\mu$. On this event, $w(T_m \cap \mathbb S^{n-1}) \leq f(\mu, m, n)$.

There are several available results for convex hulls of polytopes, but I have not yet been able to find one that e.g. uses coherence of the points describing the vertices; I have only been able to find results that depend only on $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I'd expect the mean width to decrease with the coherence, although mildly

Comment: If the coherence were 1, then it is hard to say anything about the mean width. For example, $\{e_1, -e_1, e_2, e_3, ..., e_n\}$ has a coherence of 1 and its cone is $\mathbb R^n$, while $\{e_1, 2 e_1\}$ has a coherence of $1$ and its cone is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq}$.